# Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1 Installation - Integrated or Windows authentication for SQL

Tags: 2013

I've been trying to install 2013 SP1 HR1 for the last few hours, but it keeps throwing Failed login attempts for the database connection.  The environment uses AD authentication to the SQL server with SQL authentication disabled.  Every way I've tried so far to force the HR1 installer to use AD creds or integrated authentication just seem to throw the same error.

Can someone tell me if there are any unattended parameters needed for the installer to go in to Integrated mode to install like the original 2013 SP1 installer?

Thanks

Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a defect in the SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 HR#1 installer, we aim to fix this today.

Martin, I see you have submitted a ticket so we will reach out to you when the fix is ready.

**UPDATE:** the SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 HR#1 patch installer has been updated on SDL Tridion World (https://www.sdltridionworld.com/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=/downloads/patches/SDLTridion2013/index.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

According to the install documentation (http://www.sdltridionworld.com/images/SDL%20Tridion%202013%20Installation%20Manual_tcm89-20977.pdf)

In section 4.3 you have the following

```
Install the Microsoft SQL Server database server with default options,
with the following exception: SQL and Windows authentication must be
enabled.
```

I don't think you can do this without SQL server authentication enabled.

Comment: (+1) I have installed that version several times with default options and never had that issue.